# Laravel + IE + Axios = "Promise is undefined."

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code for running AJAX requests in Laravel using Axios:

```
 axios.post('Ajax/upload',{key:this.key})
            .then(function(response)
            {
                 console.log(response);
            }).catch(function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            });
```

It works fine in Chrome, but in Internet Explorer I only get the following error:

```
Promise is udefined.
```

In the app.js file the breakpoint is set on:

```
  var chain = [dispatchRequest, undefined];
  var promise = Promise.resolve(config);
```

I have the following packages in the package.json file:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "0.18",
        "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "3.3.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "noty": "3.1.4",
        "pace-js": "1.0.2",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "popper.js": "^1.14.4"
    }
}
```

Are there any packages I need to add in order to make Axios work in Internet Explorer? Or are there any other workarounds?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: IE does not have native Promise support. This a a good polyfill: https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

Comment: Note that axios only claims to support IE11, not earlier versions, just FWIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesn't support promises out of the box, you'll need a polyfill. There are several to choose from. [MDN's promise page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) links to [this one](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise). [Axios' own documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios) links to [this one](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise).